# Symfony2 injecting Doctrine Dbal as service on constructor

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosrestbundle

Trying to pass a Doctrine dbal connection to my construct in a controller.

I am following this link to do it but it is not working:

[How do you access Doctrine DBAL in a Symfony2 service class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939214/how-do-you-access-doctrine-dbal-in-a-symfony2-service-class)

Here is my service inside app/config/config.yml

```
services:
 form1:
   class:       Test\TestBundle\Controller\FormController
   arguments:   [@doctrine.dbal.form1_connection]
```

Here is my controller with construct

```
namespace Test\TestBundle\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use FOS\RestBundle\Routing\ClassResourceInterface;
use FOS\RestBundle\Util\Codes;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;


class FormController extends FOSRestController implements ClassResourceInterface
{

    private $connection;

    public function __construct(Connection $dbalConnection)  {
        $this->connection = $dbalConnection;    
    }
}
```

I get this error "message": "Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Test\TestBundle\Controller\FormController::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\DBAL\Connection, none given, called in /srv/test/tmp/dev/cache/classes.php on line 2449 and defined in /vagrant/test.com/src/Test/TestBundle/Controller/FormController.php

Here is app/config/routing.yml

```
test_form:
    pattern:  /api/v4/forms.{_format}
    defaults: { _controller: TestTestBundle:Form:cget, _format: json }
    requirements:
        _method: GET
```

Any help would be great. thx

Comment: And how is this controller being created?  A route with a controller as a service?  Or a new FormController()?  Or directly from the container?

Comment: Its created by the app/console command line. The route for this controller is in routing.yml, its a modified route to /api/v4/forms.{_format}
Could it be that the service gets confused and can't find that route?

Comment: Can you post the relevant lines from routing.yml?  If it has something like _controller: TestBundle::Form then that will explain the problem.  It should have __controller: form1.

Comment: ok just did, perhaps you can see what the issue is. I will need to use a specific pattern of /api/v4/forms.{format} so don't know if there is another way of doing this and also keep format as json on that method under FormController. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.  The basic problem is that _controller: TestTestBundle:Form:cget does not use the service container to create the FormController.  Hence no injection.  You need to configure the controller as a service.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html

Your routing will look like:

```
test_form:
    pattern:  /api/v4/forms.{_format}
    defaults: { _controller: form1:cgetAction, _format: json }
    requirements:
        _method: GET
```

However, this will create a second problem since your controller ends up extending from the Symfony base controller which requires the container to be injected as well.  So you need to adjust your service file to something like:

```
services:
    form1:
        class:       Test\TestBundle\Controller\FormController
        arguments:   ['@doctrine.dbal.form1_connection']
        calls:
            - [setContainer, ['@service_container']]
```

I think that should get you going.

Comment: Just tried that but gave me error, "message": "You have requested a non-existent service \"form1\". Did you mean this: \"doctrine.dbal.logger.profiling.form1\"?",
"class": "Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Exception\\ServiceNotFoundException",

Comment: just found error, it was missing this:
defaults: { _controller: form1:cgetAction, _format: json }
So just edit that and we are good :), thx

Comment: My bad.  I always forget the action suffix.

Comment: this is a good question, more ppl should look at your answer :)

Comment: Well.  I am a big fan of defining controllers as services.  However, in this particular case, since you need to extend from the RestController then you already have the container which means that there is really no need to inject your connection.  The controller's action can just use $this->get('doctrine.dbal.form1_connection'); It's only when you design your controllers to not need the container that using services start to pay off.

Comment: i was doing that inside the cgetAction but then i will wanted to have it in construct as i don't wanna call one line on each action i have on REST Controller. All that line does it seeds a dynamic database based on user's profile id. So if the constructor can do it then don't have to write extra one line on 10+ actions in that controller

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your service, maybe you need this: doctrine.dbal.default_connection.

Comment: i have two connections and each one with entity manager, one of them is form1 and the other is default. Neither of them work as a service.