# Symfony2, use getDoctrine and em in class

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a Timesheet.php class in Symfony2, and i need, in this class, use for example :

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository()->find();
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->remove();
```

How can i do that ? I have try to call the class as a service, manually add variable in constructor and other but no effect...

Do you have a good solution ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `$this->getDoctrine()` is method of `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller` class. When you check this method there is `$this->container->get('doctrine')` so what you need is having `doctrine` available in your `Timesheet` class. To do so, define your `Timesheet` class as a service:

```
your.service_id:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\Timesheet
    arguments: [@doctrine]
```

Then your `Timesheet` class:

```
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;

class Timesheet
{
    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    private $doctrine;

    /**
     * @param Registry $doctrine Doctrine
     */
    public function __construct(Registry $doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    public function yourMethod()
    {
        //this is what you want to achieve, right?
        $this->doctrine->getManager()->remove();
        $this->doctrine->getRepository()->find();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless of course TimeSheet is loaded from the database.  This sort of thing should be avoided but you can do it with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25795417/symfony2-injecting-doctrine-dbal-as-service-on-constructor/25796045#25796045

Comment: @Cerad Why this thing should be avoided? I'm curios as I also used once this approach.

Comment: The basic idea is that Doctrine 2 entities really should not need to know about the details of the database.  Object Relation Managers(ORM) should focus on objects and not database tables.  It's definitely a different way of designing applications.  Plus of course, using globals is something that is generally frowned upon.  In this particular case, when the timesheet object is loaded it should already have all the relations to whatever objects it needs to know about.  Hence there should be no need to access a repository.