# Dynamic objects in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I create a system to generate and management a database. The idea is simple: User will be able to define tables, their structures and of course add/edit/remove all data. This dynamic objects should be fully configurated on website level, not in code. Let's assume that I have all necessary information from user (it was send via form) and now I would like to generate new Doctrine object and create table in a database. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
$sm = $conn->getSchemaManager();
$schema = $sm->createSchema();
$newSchema = clone $schema;
$table = $newSchema->createTable("my_table");
$table->addColumn("id", "integer", array("unsigned" => true));
$table->addColumn("username", "string", array("length" => 32));
$table->setPrimaryKey(array("id"));
$table->addUniqueIndex(array("username"));
$sql = $schema->getMigrateToSql($newSchema, $conn->getDatabasePlatform());
```

After that just execute your new sql

```
$conn->exec( $sql );
```

P.S. `conn` is the instance of `DBAL connection`. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939214/how-do-you-access-doctrine-dbal-in-a-symfony2-service-class) for more info.